# Throw error when adding additional types to predefined type

Tags: typescript, electron

I am trying to create additional type definitions for electrons `invoke` method. What I would like is for when the first value is `get`, that the method calling it errors if less than 3 items are passed or more than 3 are passed. Currently it only errors if I pass a generic to the method. Is there anything I can do to make it so it errors even without the generic?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCCiE4ALjAPaLwDeAUPPAJaJEgwBmOCAkpmAEoiJQcGFVp14AegnwACmQBu9UMHgAjAJ7wQhMCXIAuMXUbzSAaxAAKMAAsoiRNv3x0JRgHMANPAB0f2O7ozvbqANoAugCUznKkKPToIAA8IQB8ANzURpLSALKaUMDA9ET0Btkm5skAKvAAvFQAvqnWdg5O8ADk7iBEnd5wWOSJAMJtjhDOrjAe3gCuMJMuboju0bJk8YlJ1alijdQH1JBQ6Ojw1RhEI9BnomL0PPyCLCwAhM4ExGSIPtx8AiELCydBQ6gAYnNEGBLJFROIcvAAMo2UhzCAqIg2MgAdy0MDIMEMCKxCR8jwBL2E5MQpgslm6vX6XUGmGGIAAtLZ7BNOpEQeIpBdsaQced7PjCfAcTZ6LYGOcZVAiAqtAAPTDEEDAYniUnoclPQGvGA0unJaYeFqMvreTqs9lc8baPn7Q5AA)

```js
declare namespace Electron {
  interface IpcRenderer {
    // Provided by electron (node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts):
    invoke(channel: string, ...args: any[]): Promise<any>;

    // My addition:
    invoke<T = {}>(channel: 'get', responseChannel: string, url: string): Promise<T>
  }
}

class TestClass {

  ipcRenderer!: Electron.IpcRenderer

  myFunc() {
    // Should throw error:
    this.ipcRenderer.invoke('get', 'response-channel')

    // Throws an error which is what is expected:
    this.ipcRenderer.invoke<string>('get', 'response-channel')
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're only adding new method signature overloads via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)?  You can't disable the existing method that accepts just about anything?  I don't think you can add a call signature which has the effect of *prohibiting* another call signature.

Comment: You basically want [microsoft/TypeScript#19064](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19064) but nothing works like that now.  And the [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) behavior of overloads in TS makes it hard to even express the constraint you want, since there's no way to say "all strings but `"get"`".  Can you use your own interface instead like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEDa2W)?  If so I can write up an explanation; if not, I suppose the answer here is probably just "no, sorry"